# Find average and total time between dates in a row string in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The spark df column has a **list of ordered dates** demilited by '|' . It looks like this :

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|      date                                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|2018-08-01|2017-06-01|2015-11-01|2012-08-21|2010-04-02      |
|2016-08-11|2013-08-25|2013-04-01|2012-01-01                 |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**I want to calculate the average time for each row and the total difference (last date- first date) in days like this :**

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------------+
|      date                                                  | average time  | total time    |
+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------------+
|2018-08-01|2017-06-01|2015-11-01|2012-08-21|2010-08-01      |   584         | 2920          |
|2016-08-11|2013-08-25|2013-04-01|2012-08-11                 |   365         | 1460          |
+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Spark is not SPARQL ...

Comment: Thought the the total and average in the desired output aren't correct in your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use inbuilt **`array functions`** of dataframe for this case..

**`Example:`**

```
val df= Seq(("2018-08-01|2017-06-01|2015-11-01|2012-08-21|2010-04-02"),("2016-08-11|2013-08-25|2013-04-01|2012-01-01")).toDF("id") //sample data

df.withColumn("arr_id", array_sort(split(col("id"),"\\|"))). //split to create array and sort the array
withColumn("first_ele", col("arr_id")(0)). // to get first element of array
withColumn("last_ele",reverse(col("arr_id"))(0)). //to get last element of array
withColumn("total_diff",datediff(col("last_ele").cast("date"), col("first_ele").cast("date"))). //get total diff of first and last dates
withColumn("avg_time", col("total_diff")/size(col("arr_id"))). //caluculate diff of date and divide with size of array column
select("id", "total_diff","avg_time"). 
show(false)
```

**`Result:`**

```
+------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------+
|id                                                    |total_diff|avg_time|
+------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------+
|2018-08-01|2017-06-01|2015-11-01|2012-08-21|2010-04-02|3043      |608.6   |
|2016-08-11|2013-08-25|2013-04-01|2012-01-01           |1684      |421.0   |
+------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------+
```

I think the output in question and answer is off because `start and end dates` in array are little different in `input` and `output` in question!

Comment: that is scala, i think OP wants pyspark

Answer (score 1):

@Shu gave an awesome answer in Scala.

This just pyspark version. Feel free to give him the accepted answer.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("date", F.split(F.regexp_replace("date","\|",","),','))\
.withColumn("start", F.reverse(F.col("date"))[0]).withColumn("end",F.col("date")[0])\
.withColumn("total_time", F.datediff("end","start"))\
.withColumn("Average", F.col("total_time")/(F.size(F.col("date"))))\
.drop("start","end").show()

+--------------------+----------+-------+
|                date|total_time|Average|
+--------------------+----------+-------+
|[2018-08-01, 2017...|      3043|  608.6|
|[2016-08-11, 2013...|      1684|  421.0|
+--------------------+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of the other answers using array built-in functions in Spark 2.4+.

First, split the dates string to get an array. 
Now, as the dates are already sorted, use [`element_at`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/#element_at) function to get first and last dates since when the index is negative it accesses the elements of the array from last to the first. The rest is just calculating [`datediff`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/#datediff) and divide it by the size of the array to get the average:

```
df.withColumn("array_dates", split(col("date"), "[|]"))\
  .withColumn("total_time", datediff(element_at("array_dates", -1), element_at("array_dates", 1))) \
  .withColumn("average_time", col("total_time") / size(col("array_dates"))) \
  .drop("array_dates")\
  .show(2, False)


#+------------------------------------------------------+----------+------------+
#|date                                                  |total_time|average_time|
#+------------------------------------------------------+----------+------------+
#|2018-08-01|2017-06-01|2015-11-01|2012-08-21|2010-04-02|3043      |608.6       |
#|2016-08-11|2013-08-25|2013-04-01|2012-01-01           |1684      |421.0       |
#+------------------------------------------------------+----------+------------+
```

If the dates in the string aren't ordred as in your example, you could sort the array after split using [`array_sort`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/#array_sort)